# How to get difference between two day in php

Tags: php, date, datetime, datediff

I have on function which passing some parameter the like

```
everyWeekOn("Mon",11,19,00)
```

I want to compute the difference between the current day (e.g. 'Fri')
and passed parameter day i.e. `Mon`.

The output should be:

```
The difference between Mon and Fri is 3
```

I tried it like this

```
 $_dt = new DateTime();
 error_log('$_dt date'. $_dt->format('d'));
 error_log('$_dt year'. $_dt->format('Y'));
 error_log('$_dt month'. $_dt->format('m'));
```

But know I don't know what to do next to get the difference between the two days.

Note that this question is different from [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php) because I only have a day and not a complete date.

Comment: @martin my question is different please check first

Comment: Yes, thank you for the clarification, I misread it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implement `DateTime` class in conjunction with `->diff` method:

```
function everyWeekOn($day) {
    $today = new DateTime;
    $next = DateTime::createFromFormat('D', $day);
    $diff = $next->diff($today);
    return "The difference between {$next->format('l')} and {$today->format('l')} is {$diff->days}";
}

echo everyWeekOn('Mon');
```

Comment: thax @ghost you save my ass ;)

Comment: Awesome buddy thax for the help

Comment: hey ghost can you explain just what is $next->format('l') pls

Comment: @Sanji its the same thing with `date('l')`, (thats small L) http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php its using the same format. and the [`->format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new DateTime('2015-01-01 12:00:00');
$difference = $date->diff(new DateTime());
echo $difference->days.' days <br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find no. of days in two days by using this code

```
<?php
    $today = time(); 
    $chkdate = strtotime("16-04-2015");
    $date = $today - $chkdate;
    echo floor($date/(60*60*24));
?>
```

Please use this may this help you

Comment: WATCH OUT: not all days are 86400 (60*60*24) seconds long! This may have unexpected results if the server is not using UTC as timezone! Use `DateTime` and its methods instead.